# Как передать значение в новое окно сайта

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-form, jquery-form

Имеется файл "index.html". В данном файле есть текстовое поле и кнопка. Необходимо, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку открывалась страница "register.html", на которой через alert выводилось содержимое текстового поля. При попытке реализации я столкнулся с проблемой, что открывается страница "register.html", однако сообщение появляется на текущей странице, а только потом открывается нужная, хотя команда изменить страницу идет раньше вывода. Как это можно исправить?
index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Тест</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="../JS/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../JS/Lab6_js.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="new_text"></input>
        <button id="btn">Enter</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    function new_window(data){
        window.location.href="register.html";
        alert(data);
    }

    $("#btn").on("click", function () {
        new_window(document.getElementById("new_text").value);
    });
})
```

register.html пустой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как минимум можно этими способами:

- Можете записать в [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), а потом после перехода считать оттуда значение переменной
- Можете передать с помощью `query` параметров, а потом считать с помощью [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)